# ARIMA timeseries forecasting model gives error for predicting sales values while same code works for SARIMAX model,Why?

Tags: python, statsmodels

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
AReg=sm.tsa.ARIMA(store1_df_new, order=(1, 0, 1))
res_ARIMA=AReg.fit()

# to make the predictions for 11 steps ahead
predictions_int = res_ARIMA.forecast(steps=11)
predictions_int.mean
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22460/496918018.py in 
1 # make the predictions for 11 steps ahead
2 predictions_int1 = res_ARIMA.forecast(steps=11)
----> 3 predictions_int1.mean

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'mean'

```
Weekly_Sales
```

Date
2010-02-05  1643690.90
2010-02-12  1641957.44
2010-02-19  1611968.17
2010-02-26  1409727.59
2010-03-05  1554806.68
... ...
2012-09-28  1437059.26
2012-10-05  1670785.97
2012-10-12  1573072.81
2012-10-19  1508068.77
2012-10-26  1493659.74

Comment: Hi, did you look at `predictions_int` itself or did you look at `help(res_ARIMA.forecast)` or encountered the warning *FutureWarning:
statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have
been deprecated in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA (note the .
between arima and model) and
statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX. These will be removed after the 0.12 release.*?

Comment: I checked for just prediction_int values in both cases

Comment: Okay then maybe have a look at `help(res_ARIMA.forecast)`, too.